# Why does the Chatan arrive first to the Chuppa?

Tags: wedding, chupah

At every wedding I have attended, I have seen that the *Chattan* (groom) arrives at the *chuppah* before the *kallah* (bride).

Is this a halachic requirement? Please provide both a source as well as the reason for this.

Comment: Note that a lot of things we do at weddings are minhag and not halacha.

Comment: @ezra Even more of them are neither minhag nor halacha, just people do them because it's socially expected or they've never thought about it.

Comment: In מהרי"ל הלכות נישואין it describes it that way. It is not concrete proof, as it was done in the Synagogue after davening, so it only makes sense to be done in that order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Rama](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7681) (Even HaEzer 55:1) quotes the Ran that the Chuppa is the bride going into the domain of the husband.

So it makes sense for the husband to be there first, so the Chuppah could rightfully be called "his house"

The [Nitei Gavriel](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&pgnum=126) Nisuin 1 (17:5:11) also quotes the [Likkutei Maharich](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=48754&st=&pgnum=292) that it's to make it clear that the Kallah realizes who she's marrying.

The Likkutei Maharich also quotes the Zohar which mentions [Gershon's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80148/732) answer (that it's derived from the verse "I gave my daughter to this man").

Comment: `So it makes sense for the husband to be there first, so the Chuppah could rightfully be called "his house"` Do you have any evidence that simply being there first makes it 'rightfully be called "his house"'?

Comment: @mevaqesh no, that's why I said "it makes sense" - When you take someone into your house, you tend to be there first.

Comment: What does the order they arrive in have to do with free choice?

Comment: @mevaqesh If she came first, she can claim later than she never intended to get married to _this_ groom.

Comment: Then why did she accept kiddushin from him?

Comment: @mevaqesh she wasn't paying attention when he gave her the ring?

Answer (score 2):

A reason I have heard is that similar to the Chupa of Adam and Chava like is explained in more detail by [Rabbi Bernie Fox with the Orthodox Union](https://www.ou.org/torah/parsha/rabbi-fox-on-parsha/adam-chava-model-marriage/).

In context, the Torah says that Chava was brought to Adam.

[Breishis 2:22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8166#v=22&showrashi=true)

> And the Lord God built the side that He had taken from man into a
>   woman, and He brought her to man.